# AS400/Iseries/DB2 SQL - Select unique view / logical

Tags: sql, db2

I'm looking for some help creating a view / logical over the below. Ideally I want to ignore the dept column, and then select the unique users and email addresses. For example you can see below USER1 works for 2 departments... but I only want to see them once in the view/logical.

Any help on the syntax for this would be great. My select unique always seems to give the wrong result as it still references DEPT, therefore I still see all records

```
| USER| DEPT| EMAIL|
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| USER1| SALES| user1@email.com|
| USER2| SALES| user2@email.com|
| USER1| FINANCE| user1@email.com|
| USER4| IT| user4@email.com|
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT USER, EMAIL FROM TABLE?